# How can I retrieve multiple rows from a table and display the combined information in a single query?

Tags: mysql

I have used a dynamic form builder plugin in WordPress. When I input some data from this form data inserted in the table. The table looks like below.

```
id    entry_id    field_id       slug            value
1     1           fld_7213434    name            abc
2     1           fld_5474822    father          def
3     1           fld_4459896    gender          Female
4     1           fld_6364274    village_name    ijk
20    2           fld_7213434    name            J Jahan
21    2           fld_5474822    father          Md Ali
22    2           fld_4459896    gender          Female
23    2           fld_6364274    village_name    ijk
```

I need to show this table's data like below

```
S.N.   name      father   gender    village_name
1      abc       def      Female    ijk
2      J Jahan   Md Ali   Female    Adabor
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Not a whole lot of PHP code here for a PHP question. This matters a lot in terms of context.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to join the table to itself:

```
SELECT 
    t1.entry_id `S.N.`,
    t1.value name,
    t2. value father,
    t3.value gender,
    t4.value village_name
FROM mytable t1
LEFT JOIN mytable t2 ON t2.entry_id = t1.entry_id AND t2.field_id = 'fld_5474822'
LEFT JOIN mytable t3 ON t3.entry_id = t1.entry_id AND t3.field_id = 'fld_4459896'
LEFT JOIN mytable t4 ON t4.entry_id = t1.entry_id AND t4.field_id = 'fld_6364274'
WHERE
    t1.field_id = 'fld_7213434'
```

Of course, instead of `mytable` you have to use your correct table name that you have not mentioned in your question.

A join is the Cartesion product ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)) of all involved tables. After filtering the resulting set of rows for those with the correct combinations (in this case, `entry_id` and `field_id` must be filtered), you get exactly what you want.

For performance reasons, you might want to have an index on the columns `entry_id` and `field_id`, but you'll find out.